# Reason for debug assertion in this code

Tags: c++, destructor, c++03

Suppose that I have this code - this code does nothing and I understand that their is a memory leak as the destructor of car is not virtual. However I do not understand why I get a debug assertion for this code. I am using visual studio 2010.

```
struct car {
    ~car() 
    {std::cout << "Destructor of car";  }
};
struct honda: public car {
     virtual ~honda()
    { std::cout << "Destructor of honda"; }
};

int main()
{
    car *c = new honda();
    delete c;
}
```

I do not get this assertion if destructor of `honda` class is not declared virtual. I wanted to know what is the issue with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the destructor `virtual`, you need to declare it as such *in the base class*:

```
struct car {
    virtual ~car() {std::cout << "Destructor of car";  }
 // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
};
```

Without this, your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

To make your derived class destructor virtual, you must have your base class destructor virtual as well. 
See [C++ assertion error while deleting object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768468/c-assertion-error-while-deleting-object) for a detailed explanation.

The reason the assert goes away when the destructor of `honda` is not virtual is that it becomes well defined. Although, it is recommended to have base class destructor(s) to be virtual to get the destruction calls through the inheritance hierarchy.