# 2D Vector Causing Memory Leak

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I am currently working on a 2d platformer game in C++.
I have a class called Tilemap which stores the actual data for the tilemap in a 2D int vector. I noticed that when the player dies and I restart the level the process memory goes up by about 1 Megabyte. So I used Visual Leak Detector and it detected 114 memory leaks all originating from the initialization of my 2D int vector.
Here's my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> tileMapArray;
tileMapArray.resize(mapSizeX);
for (int i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++)
    tileMapArray[i].resize(mapSizeY);
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks in advance,
TheKrane

---

EDIT: Those are the lines that VLD tells me the leaks occur at:

main.cpp(30):

```
Scene* currentLevel = new Level;
```

level.cpp(6):

```
Level::Level() : m_Tilemap("Data/testlevel.tmx", "Data/tilemap.png") {}
```

tilemap.cpp(36):

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++)
    tileMapArray[i].resize(mapSizeY);
```

Comment: The problem is not with this snippet of code.

Comment: Where else could it be?

Comment: Looks like you are not deleting `currentLevel`. VLD only tells you where the memory has been allocated.

Comment: currentLevel is deleted properly

Comment: I think found the problem.
Level dervives from a base class called Scene. Now only the destructor of the scene class is called when I delete Level. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a virtual destructor

Comment: If I use a virtual destructor for the base class I get a Debug Assertion Error when I delete the Level object as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768468/c-assertion-error-while-deleting-object